# How to choose a coordinate reference system

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, jpg

I have a jpeg image of a reserve's layout and would like to use it to plot animals movements on i.e. GPS points. I have no idea which coordinate reference system to choose during the "georeferencing" process.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to include whereabouts in the world you are observing these animal movements, please?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the region you're working in. As you are using GPS data, i suggest using a UTM system. You can look up a suitable zone on [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Utm-zones.jpg) grid.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you are using an image with GPS data in it the information is going to have been most likely stored in WGS84.

Identify the part of the world you are working in, either by researching the source of the image and or imformation on the image. From there either project the GPS data using WGS84 as the datum into an appropriate UTM Zone that covers your work area.

Or explore what coordinate reference systems are appropriate for the area of interest with appropriate methods of transformation/conversion if nessessary.

1. Have a look at using [epsg.io](http://epsg.io) or use the OGP EPSG Area Polygons
   as Searchable Layers which is available to download from
   [arcgis.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2ff6d44a19854280aec1d56368e12605). These resources may help with identifying appropriate coordinate systems.