# Convert Excel addresses to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, excel, address

I have an Excel file with about 70 addresses. Is there a way to import these addresses into ArcMap to show up as points in the correct location? 
Or do I need to pick a coordinate system?

If so, how do I decide which one?

Basically, I need to find out the distance from each of these addresses to two locations.

Comment: What do you mean by: `to show up as points in the correct?`  Do you mean the correct location?  Can you provide more information on the addresses, for example do they have actual coordinates, or do you just have the address with post code/zip code?  Also you seem to have more than one question, [1] How to import excel data? perhaps [2] How to convert addresses to coordinates? and [3] How to calculate distance from an address to a location?  Have you tried anything?  You'll need to edit your question to provide this extra information, and note there should be only one question.

Comment: Can you post screen shot of your excel spreadsheet?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99645/how-to-choose-a-coordinate-reference-system

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.